# if-else jinja expression adds extra space to values

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I'm using the below code in my playbook:

```
- set_fact:
     value1: "{% if 1==0 %}{{ true }}
              {% else %}{{ false }}
              {% endif %}"
- debug: "{{ value1 }}"
```

The output I'm expecting is 'false' but the actual output is "False ". Notice the extra space after value due to which the boolean is treated as a string.

If I'm putting the expressions in a single line as:

```
- set_fact:
     value1: "{% if 1==0 %}{{ true }}{% else %}{{ false }}{% endif %}"
- debug: "{{ value1 }}"
```

Then the output value is boolean, but this reduces the readability of code, especially if expressions are large.

Is there a way to get boolean value in multiline if-else jinja expression?

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [whitespace control](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#whitespace-control) in jinja.
As you can see from the link, there are multiple ways to do this, one of them is this:

**BAD CODE:**
It is usually considered bad style to something like `if (boolean condition): then return true` because you can do `return (boolean condition)`.

```yaml
- set_fact:
     value1: "{%- if 1==0 -%}{{ true }}
              {%- else -%}{{ false }}
              {%- endif -%}"
- debug: "{{ value1 }}"
```

This is actually way too complicated. Check out this:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    value1: "{{ 1 == 0 }}"
- debug:
    msg: "{{ value1 }}"
```

This will give you a boolean.

By the way, when handling boolean values in ansible, it is usually a good idea to use the [bool filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#forcing-the-data-type).

Answer (score 0):

Using below resolved the issue:

- set_fact:
  value1: "{% if 1==0 %}{{ true }}
  {%- else %}{{ false }}
  {%- endif %}"
- debug: "{{ value1 }}"

Comment: hey, I used something like this today and found a way better way to do it. Check out the edit on my answer.